# angular io highchart socket io

Tags: highcharts, socket.io

i have this little problem i think it is about asynch message.
when i try to add a dot on the chart it add the value of the data but not the dot.
Do you have an idea?

module ==>

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})

export class AppComponent{
  url = 'http://localhost:5000';  
  socket : any;
  chart : any;
  options: any;
  v:any;
  constructor() {
  this.socket = io.connect(this.url);
  this.options = {
      title: { text : 'chart with dynamic data' },
      series: [{
          data: [2,3,5,8]
      }]
  }
  this.getMessages();
}

saveInstance(chartInstance) {
    this.chart = chartInstance.context;
}
addPoint(n:any) {
    this.chart.series[0].addPoint(n);
}
sendMessage(n:any){

  this.socket.emit('add-message',n);    
}
getMessages() {
    this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        this.addPoint(data);
    })
}
```

}

html ==>

```
<chart [options]="options" (load)="saveInstance($event)"></chart>
<input #v (keyup.enter)="sendMessage(v.value)">
```

Comment: Your code is not complete and it cannot reproduce the problem. That behaviour occurs if you add string/undefined instead of number as a point. Make sure you convert string to number/not sending null before you use addPoint() method

Comment: Perfect ! ParseInt() was the solution so simple ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ParseInt() was the right solution thx you morganfree